# Jordan Normal form: problems with finding correct generalized eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have been tasked to find the Jordan Normal Form for the matrix $A$ shown below. 
\begin{align*}
A = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 5 & 2 & -1 \\
0 & -4 & 0 & 4
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
In itself, finding a Jordan Normal form is not that hard, but I'm having some problems with determining the correct coordinate transformation, namely finding the correct generalized eigenvectors.

What I have done so far:

The characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4 - 8 \lambda^3 + 24 \lambda^2 -32 \lambda + 16 = (\lambda - 2)^4$, so we get eigenvalue $\lambda = 2$ with algebraic multiplicity 4.

The kernel of $(A - 2I)$ is
\begin{align*}
\ker\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -2 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 5 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & -4 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} = \text{L}((0,0,1,0)^T, (-3,1,0,2)^T)
\end{align*}
so our first two eigenvectors are $(0,0,1,0)^T$ and $(-3,1,0,2)^T$, and we are two vectors short.

Following this we determine $\ker((A-2I)^2)$ and we get
\begin{align*}
\ker\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & -4 & 0 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}
Now I thought that if we take $v = (0,1,0,2)^T$ and $w = (0,0,0,1)^T$ from $\ker((A-2I)^3)$, then we have $(A - 2I)v \neq 0$ and $(A - 2I)w \neq 0$. Also, the four vectors are linearly independent and generate $\mathbb{R}^4$, so we have a good basis.

However, when using this basis as coordinate transformation, you do not get the Jordan Normal Form $J$ that MATLAB and Wolfram calculate. That is, you do not get a Jordan Normal form at all.
\begin{align*}
J = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

My question is thus, where am I making a mistake? Also, I am wondering why is $J$ split into a $3 \times 3$ and a $1 \times 1$ block, is it not supposed to be one big $4 \times 4$ block?

If anyone could provide some hints or point me in the right direction, I'd be forever grateful, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JNF of $A$ should be $Q^{-1}AQ$, where $Q$ is the matrix having a Jordan basis as its columns.

The basis which you found is not a Jordan basis, so it is not a disjoint union of Jordan
chains.

**Different method of getting JNF:**

**Theorem**.
Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of a matrix $A$ and let $J$ be the JNF of $A$. Then
the number of Jordan blocks of $J$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$ is equal to
$\mbox{nullity} (A − \lambda I)$.

Are you familiar with it?

In your calculations the $\mbox{nullity} (A − 2I)=2$. Thus $J$ will be of the form
$J_{\lambda}^{(k)} \oplus J_{\lambda}^{(l)}$ for some natural numbers $k$,$l$ depending on the characteristic and minimal polynomial of $A$ and such that $k+l=4$, where

Let $J_{\lambda}^{(n)}=\left[ \begin{array}{llll}
\lambda_i & 1            & \;     & \;  \\
\;        & \lambda_i    & \ddots & \;  \\
\;        & \;           & \ddots & 1   \\
\;        & \;           & \;     & \lambda_n
\end{array} \right].$

Note that the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $m_A(\lambda)=(\lambda-2)^3$, thus the only option of JNF is $J_{2}^{(3)} \oplus J_{2}^{(1)}=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}.
$

Comment: For our course we use a 'dictate' that in my opinion is quite lacking. It only presents the theory on what a JNF is, and has only one example on how to find it. I thus have no understanding about what defines a Jordan basis (other than that it leads to a JNF), nor do I know the connection between minimal polynomials and the JNF. Now that I'm typing this up I realize that I might need a better 
book...

The theorem you provided is quite interesting though, and it clears up why the JNF is split that way, so thanks for that!

Comment: In the meanwhile I'll look for some more info on the Jordan basis, but since you are probably more knowledgable than me on this subject: what linear algebra book discussing this topic would you personally recommend ?

Comment: Try 'Jordan Canonical Form Theory and Practice' by Steven H.Weintraub http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Jordan_Canonical_Form.html?id=qDPMLisVSCIC&redir_esc=y

Comment: Using your theorem and combining that with info on the web I found the chains $\{(-3,1,0,2)^T\}$ and $\{(0,0,2,0)^T, (-1,1,-1,2)^T, (0,0,0,1)^T \}$, which solves my problem. I know now where I'm missing theory. I'll look into your recommended book, and thank you very much for your help!