# What is wrong with my derivation of Jordan normal form?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, fake-proofs

EDIT:
A key error in my working is that it allows $M$ to be singular! I tried to solve $AM=MJ$, not realising that $M^{-1}AM=J$ requires $M^{-1}$ to exist and be completely linearly independent!

OP:
Reading Wikipedia, I saw examples of JNF but did not see a clear explanation for why it works, so I attempted to show it to myself - and I thought I had proven it, until I read [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599899/jordan-normal-form-problems-with-finding-correct-generalized-eigenvectors) post on MSE, which claimed that the only way to express the matrix in JNF was with a very specific block count, and block size - the number of blocks with a certain eigenvalue $\lambda$ must apparently be the nullity of $A-\lambda I$, which clashes entirely with my "understanding" of why JNF works.

$A\in M_{n\times n}$ can be written in JNF by $M^{-1}AM=J\implies AM=MJ$, where $M$ is the "modal" matrix, and $J$ is the JNF of $A$. Wikipedia's example constructed the JNF by calculating the eigenvectors and generalised eigenvectors, creating Jordan chains of such vectors, and grouping the chains in correspondence with the Jordan blocks. My erroneous "proof" went as follows:

For convenience, let the matrix $B=A-\lambda I$. Let the Jordan chain of some such eigenvalue $\lambda$, for which the generalised eigenvector is of rank $m$, be written $\mathfrak{Ch}(\lambda)=\{x_m,x_{m-1},\dots,x_1\}$, and let $\mathfrak{Ch}_i(\lambda)=x_i$ in the chain, where all the $x_i$ are related by $B^mx_m=0;x_1=B^{m-1}x_m\neq0;x_{i}=Bx_{i+1}$. $J=\bigoplus_{i=1}^n J_k(\lambda_i)$, where $\lambda_i$ is the relevant eigenvalue depending on your chosen order of constructing $J$, and $k$ is the size of the relevant Jordan block, depending on $i$. $M$ is constructed (I thought) by using, as its column vectors, any series of vectors from $\mathfrak{Ch}(\lambda_i)$, such that the eigenvalue $\lambda_i$ in that section of $M$ corresponds with the Jordan block in $J$.

The product $MJ$ is expressible in the form of a sequence of column vectors $c_i$. Letting the Jordan block corresponding to that column $i$ have a relative index $k$ to represent the $k$th column of the Jordan block and also to represent the $k$th column in the series of chain-vectors in $M$ (as they must correspond - I think!):

Since the Jordan block at some column $k$ has the form $\begin{pmatrix}\lambda\\0\\0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$,$\begin{pmatrix}1\\\lambda\\0\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}\vdots\\0\\1\\\lambda\\\vdots\end{pmatrix}$ the product for $c_i$ evaluates to $\mathfrak{Ch}_{k-1}(\lambda)+\lambda\cdot\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda)$, defining "$\mathfrak{Ch}_0(\lambda)$" to be zero to account for the case $k=1$, where there is no trailing one in the Jordan block to catch the previous column of $M$ in the product. By the chain identities above, $\mathfrak{Ch}_{k-1}(\lambda)+\lambda\cdot\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda)=B\times\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda)+\lambda I\times\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda))=(B+\lambda I)\times\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda)=A\times\mathfrak{Ch}_k(\lambda)$, which I believe is precisely the product in the column $i$ of $AM$, therefore asserting $MJ=AM$ to be true when (and I'd have thought *only* when) $M, J$ are constructed as I've described.

Evidently (since my method comprehensively failed to solve the question that I linked, and clashes with what the answerer said) my idea of why JNF works and how we construct it is wrong - but why?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument seems to go wrong as soon as you define $\mathfrak{Ch}(\lambda)$ to mean "*the* Jordan chain of some eigenvalue $\lambda$". If the Jordan form has more than one block with the same eigenvalue, it will be because there are several *independent* Jordan chains for the same $\lambda$ -- in other words, a single chain might not be enough to span the entire generalized eigenspace.

---

If you want to think of just one chain, it needs to be a chain of *subspaces*, rather than single vectors:
$$ V_{n+1} = V_n \supseteq V_{n-1} \supseteq \cdots \supseteq V_1 \supseteq V_0 = \{0\} $$
where each $V_k$ is the preimage of $V_{k-1}$ under $A-\lambda I$. Or, in other words, $V_k$ is the null space of $(A-\lambda I)^k$.

If we just choose a basis for $V_1$ and extend it successively to $V_2, V_3, \ldots V_n$, the matrix for $A$ (assuming for simplicity that $\lambda$ is its only eigenvalue) under the resulting basis will be something you might call a "generalized Jordan block"

$$\begin{pmatrix} \lambda I_{d_1\times d_1} & F_1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & \lambda I_{d_2\times d_2} & F_2  & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & \lambda I_{d_{n-1}\times d_{n-1}} & F_{n-1} \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & \lambda I_{d_n\times d_n} \end{pmatrix} $$
where $d_k = \dim V_k/V_{k-1}$.

This is not *quite* nice -- we have $\lambda$s on the diagonal like we want, but the mediating blocks $F_k$ can be arbitrary (almost: it turns out each of them has full rank), and they're not even necessarily square.
By constructing our basis with a bit more care, we can achieve a nicer form, namely where each $F_k$ is an identity block, possibly extended with some zero rows on the bottom. Then a suitable permutation of the basis will produce a proper Jordan form consisting of $d_1$ Jordan blocks.

First set $\mathfrak B_{n+1}=\varnothing$. It will be an invariant that $\mathfrak B_k$ is a "basis for $V_k/V_{k-1}$", by which slight abuse of terminology I mean that $\mathfrak B_k$ together with any basis for $V_{k-1}$ will constitute a basis for $V_k$. (More precisely, $\mathfrak B_k$ consists of *representatives* of the cosets chosen as basis vectors for the quotient space $V_k/V_{k-1}$). In particular, $\mathfrak B_k \subseteq V_k \setminus V_{k-1}$.

Now, to construct $\mathfrak B_k$ for $k=n, n-1, n-2, \ldots, 1$ (in that order), start by considering the vectors
$$ \mathfrak B'_{k+1} = (A-\lambda I)\mathfrak B_{k+1} = \{ (A-\lambda I)v \mid v\in \mathfrak B_{k+1} \} \subseteq V_k $$
No nontrivial linear combination of these vectors can be in $V_{k-1}$, because the corresponding combination of vectors in $\mathfrak B_{k+1}$ would then be in $V_{k}$, which contradicts $\mathfrak B_{k+1}$ being a basis for $V_{k+1}/V_k$. In particular, this means that $\mathfrak B'_{k+1}$ is linearly independent, and it remains linearly independent together with a basis for $V_{k-1}$. So we can extend this combination to a basis for $V_k$, and forget the temporary basis for $V_{k-1}$. Now, let $\mathfrak B_k$ be the resulting set.

At the end of this, $\mathfrak B_1 \cup \cdots \cup \mathfrak B_n$ is a basis for the generalized eigenspace. And more: Whenever $|\mathfrak B_k|>|\mathfrak B_{k+1}|$ -- that is, when we needed to add additional vectors to $\mathfrak B'_{k+1}$ -- each of those additional vectors is the beginning of a Jordan chain whose elements are in $\mathfrak B_k, \mathfrak B_{k-1}, \ldots, \mathfrak B_1$, and this chain produces exactly a Jordan block of its own.

Note that the number and sizes of Jordan blocks we get this way depend only on the *dimensions* of the subspaces $V_k$, which had a completely basis-free definition. Namely, there are $\dim V_k/V_{k-1} - \dim V_{k+1}/V_{k}$ Jordan blocks of size $k$. It is simple to verify that this formula holds in particular if $A$ was *already* in Jordan form. So it is true not only for the Jordan form we constructed by the above, but for *every* Jordan form of a matrix.

The *total* number of blocks of any size (for the eigenvalue $\lambda$) is
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \bigl[\dim V_{k}/V_{k-1} - \dim V_{k+1}/V_{k}\bigr]
= \dim V_1 / V_0 - \dim V_{n+1}/V_n
= \dim V_1 $$
that is, just the nullity of $A-\lambda I$.

Comment: Thank you, I will review the formalism of this proof - it will take a while to digest - but the key point about the spaces all being linearly independent of one another is key, and now I've corrected my method and everything works now! Is there a name for the theorem you stated, to do with the nullity of $A-\lambda I$, that I might be able to research?

Comment: @IdioticShrike: Hmm, the block-counting formula here is cute enough that it probably has a name, but I don't know what it is -- I made it all up while writing :-)

Comment: @IdioticShrike: However, if _all_ you are interested in is the total number of Jordan blocks being the nullity of $A-\lambda I$, that is really just a matter of imagining how to solve $(A-\lambda I)v=0$ by good old Gaussian elimination. If $A$ is _already_ in Jordan form, the free parameters correspond exactly to the first column of each Jordan block (or last column, if your Jordan blocks have the units _below_ the diagonal), so the dimension of the null space is exactly the number of Jordan blocks.

Comment: What I’m trying to derive is a proof for why this algorithm always creates the matrices $M,J$ such that $M{-1}AM$ *always* puts $A$ in JNF, as $J$. I appreciate the algorithm, but as always when I learn about something in math, I seek to understand how we can say “it always works”! To help me with your formal construction, could you say if the “quotient set” $V_{n+1}/V_n$ means that some vector is in the kernel of one, but not the other (as how generalised eigenvectors are defined)?

Comment: @IdioticShrike: My answer was not meant as a recipe for calculations (it could be used for that, but I doubt it is the most efficient way to go about it), but precisely as a suggestion for how to _think_ about what is happening to convince yourself it works. Are you comfortable with the concept of a quotient of vector spaces in general?

Comment: my education is most unstructured and guided by the YouTube algorithm and Wikipedia links... it’s something I can research to death if I so choose, and I may well do that since your answer looked very interesting and something worth learning! But no, for now much of your argument isn’t obvious to me

Comment: @IdioticShrike: I am sorry I could not come up with something simpler. While I'd warmly recommend looking up quotient spaces (they will be handy to know about in a wide range of situations other than Jordan decompositions in particular), I think you can mostly ignore them here. Just consider "basis for $V_k/V_{k-1}$" to be a fancy way of saying "some vectors that you can append to a basis for $V_{k-1}$ to make it into a basis for $V_k$", and $\dim V_k/V_{k-1}$ is just $\dim(V_k) - \dim(V_{k-1})$.

Comment: thank you, and don’t apologise! Getting the real details is important to me, whether I understand them or not. Dumbed-down explanations often miss the whole picture, which is one of the reasons I love this site, as the true answers and ideas are often to be found here

Comment: @IdioticShrike: Note well that in this case the "real details" _are actually_ the "some vectors that you can append to a basis for $V_{k-1}$ to make it into a basis for $V_k$" description. When I said "basis for $V_k/V_{k-1}$", that was strictly speaking an abuse of terminology. I chose it because I hoped it might make it easier to make some intuitive connections for a reader who already knows about quotient spaces, not because it's technically accurate here (which it isn't).

Comment: thanks for the clarification; what would be the strictly formal terminology here?

Comment: @IdioticShrike: I tried looking around for an existing name, but found none. So the most accurate description I have to offer is in fact "a set of vectors that you can append to a basis for $V_{k-1}$ to get a basis for $V_k$". (It's a fairly easy exercise to prove that if you have such a set that works with _one_ basis for $V_{k-1}$, it will also work with any other basis for $V_{k-1}$).

Comment: thank you for your patience! +rep

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you have not worked through many matrices where the Jordan form is not diagonal. As with continued fractions, the development is alphabet soup; better to do  examples.

These are from a book by Evar D. Nering, second edition.  I will put both examples here,  check for typing errors... the eigenvalues are integers,

Made up this one,

$$ C_{jagy} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
2&7&9 \\
0&2&8 \\
0&0&2 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

When everything is an integer, I like a sort of backwards order: the one denominator is in finding the inverse of a square matix. Here, $(C-2I)^3 = 0.$  To get the 1's above the diagonal, find column $p_3$ with $(C-2I)^2 p_3 \neq  0.$ Then column $p_2 = (C-2I)p_3.$  Finally $p_1 = (C-2I)p_2$  is a genuine eigenvector. Make the matrix $P$ from the columns $p_1, p_2, p_3.$  The determinant of your choice of $P$ is the denominator in finding $P^{-1}.$ Finally $J=P^{-1}C P$ is in Jordan form.

$$  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc     \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc \bigcirc  \bigcirc $$

$$ A_{nering} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
1&0&-1&1&0 \\
-4&1&-3&2&1 \\
-2&-1&0&1&1 \\
-3&-1&-3&4&1 \\
-8&-2&-7&5&4 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

---

$$ B_{nering} =
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
5&-1&-3&2&-5 \\
0&2&0&0&0 \\
1&0&1&1&-2 \\
0&-1&0&3&1 \\
1&-1&-1&1&1 \\
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: I will work through these later; may I ask what about the JNF being non-diagonal contradicts anything in my proof? I thought that none of my claims or conclusions were based on the JNF being purely diagonal

Comment: It is indeed true that I've never successfully converted a non-diagonalisable matrix into JNF, and my method (which I thought was the main method!) has only ever worked on diagonalisable matrices, but in the spirit of mathematical curiosity I would like to see the error in my formalism/failed "proof". In particular, the origin of the theorem stated in the linked question, to do with nullity, is of interest and appears key.

Comment: @IdioticShrike  I can't say that I'm worried about your results. There are people on this site  who will read your material. I should emphasize  the minimal polynomial: for each eigenvalue, the largest Jordan block  size is the degree of $x - \lambda$ in the minimal polynomial. It appears that I should find some smaller, maybe 2 by 2 and 3 by 3....